# Ignore duplicated rows with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to display unique rows after joining 2 tables :

**Book**

```
Id        Title
12        Title 1
13        Title 2
14        Title 3
```

**Author**

```
Id  BookId    Name
1   12        Steeve
2   13        Michel
3   13        Robert
```

The result expected is to display the last Id( last entry) when a BookId is found more than once in the Author Table :

**My actual LINQ code**

```
from book in Books
join author in Authors on book.Id equals author.BookId into gr1
from join1 in gr1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

**Actual Result**

```
BookId   AuthorId
12       1 
13       2
13       3
14       NULL
```

**Expected Result**

```
BookId   AuthorId
12       1 
13       3
14       NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is that the expected result? Those rows are not duplicates - the `AuthorId`s are different. So I guess what you mean is you want only one record for each `BookId` but then what to do if there are several `AuthodId`s?

Comment: Group by BookId and then select LastOrDefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
var query = from book in Books
            join author in Authors on book.Id equals author.BookId into gr1
            select new { BookId = book.Id, AuthorId = gr1.LastOrDefault()?.Id };
```

[Fiddle Me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3T0n7y)

Comment: @GiladGreen Almost, but yours will not compile. Plus I created a fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

try a where clause

```
from book in Books
join author in Authors on book.Id equals author.BookId into gr1
from join1 in gr1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where author.authorID != null
```

Comment: This will not give me the BookId 14